# Fundamental Group of 2 torus

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

So using Vam-kampen, I obtained the fundamental group for the genus two surface to be
$$\langle a,b,c,d|aba^{-1}b^{-1}(cdc^{-1}d^{-1})^{-1}\rangle = \langle a,b,c,d|aba^{-1}b^{-1}dcd^{-1}c^{-1}\rangle $$

But I know that the genus two surface has presentation $\langle a,b,c,d| aba^{-1}b^{-1}cdc^{-1}d^{-1} \rangle$. And I know algebraically they seem the same, but in terms of loops in the fundamental group are these two spaces the same? I'm pretty sure my solution using S.V.K was done properly and the reason it is inversed is due to the amalgamated free product that requires you to invert the element that the generator maps to.

Also does I'm wondering is this group $\mathbb{Z}^4$? I know $\mathbb{Z}^2$ has presentation $\langle a,b| aba^{-1}b^{-1}\rangle$ but I'm not sure when you add other generators if this means the same thing. i.e. if this means the elements commute.

Comment: No, $\mathbb{Z^4}$ is the abelianization of this group, not the group itself. Actually, $\mathbb{Z^n}\cong F_n/[F_n,F_n]$ where $F_n$ is a free group on $n$ elements. So $\mathbb{Z^n}=\langle a_1,...,a_n|\ \  [a_i,a_j]\ \forall\ i\ne j\rangle$. On the other hand, your group is presented only by the commutators $[a,b], [c,d]$, that is a different group. (it is not abelian)

Comment: I believe your presentation and the one you know from elsewhere just differ by the labeling of the generators. If you swap your $c$ and $d$ you get the same presentation.

Comment: @Mark  so the group I got does not have a nice name? It just simply has that presentation?

Comment: @Sasha It is the fundamental group of genus $2$ surface. Don't know about other names.

Comment: You should not call this surface a "2-torus", the latter means $S^1\times S^1$. The right name is "genus 2 surface." Fundamental groups of surfaces are usually called "surface groups."